# Forward declaration of QDate class gives errors

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qdate

I'm developing an application using Qt Widgets.

In my header files, I like to forward declare classes instead of including them. At the beginning of a header file I put forward declarations as follows:

```
class QFile;
class QDate;
class QTime;
```

And, there is a function declaration in the class as the following:

```
static bool addGoldTransaction(QFile *transactionsFile, Gold goldType, OperationType transactionType, float price, float amount, QDate date, QTime time);
```

When I try to compile, it gives an error like the following:

```
forward declaration of 'class QDate'
in definition of macro 'QT_FORWARD_DECLARE_STATIC_TYPES_ITER'
in expansion of macro 'QT_FOR_EACH_STATIC_CORE_CLASS'
In file included from moc_transaction.cpp:9:0:
error: initializing argument 6 of 'static bool addGoldTransaction(QFile*, Gold, OperationType, float, float, QDate, QTime)'
```

There is no error for forward declarations of other Qt-related classes.

Including the `QDate` header file solves the issue but I wonder:

1. Why does the compiler complain only about `QDate` class while it doesn't complain about other classes? Is there anything special with `QDate` class related to this issue?
2. How can I forward declare `QDate` class?

Comment: The 6th parameter of `addGoldTransaction` takes a `QDate` by value so it's full definition must be known by then so it can be copied (ie know it's size).  A forward declaration just introduces a name it says nothing about the size of the object.

Comment: The 7th parameter of `addGoldTransaction` takes a `QTime` by value too. But it doesn't complain about anything. What is special with `QDate` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass 6 and 7 arguments of types `QDate` and `QTime` by references `QDate&` and `QTime&` or better by const references `const QDate&` and `const QTime&`.

Comment: Yes, it solves the issue. But why does the compiler does not complain about the 7th argument (QTime) while it is complaining about the 6th one (QDate) when I declare the function as in the question?

Comment: I assume the compiler reports the first error occurrence in one line. If you fix only the 6th argument, then the compiler reports new error in the 7th argument.

Comment: Yeah, I've just tried that. It solves the issue. I now can use forward declaration for both QDate and QTime.